# Подключение к удаленному репозиторию с имеющимися ключами

Tags: git, git-commit

Всем привет. Имеется удаленный репозиторий на git, но при подключении к нему запрашивает пароль. Взял паблик и приват ключи для ssh, но как их подключить в git?

Comment: А какой именно удаленный репозиторий? github? gitlab? что то свое?

Comment: Что-то свое. Мои ключи там не пропишут.

Comment: Тогда нельзя. Что бы пользоваться ключами, нужно, что бы Ваш публичный ключ "правильно прописали на стороне git сервера". Если этого не могут/не хотят - тогда придется по старинке.

Comment: Если ваши ключи не пропишут -- то никак. Договаривайтесь об этом, проверяйте возможность зайти по ssh, потому уже подключайтесь к гиту.

Comment: По паролю заходит? Если да, то скопируйте ключи с помощью `ssh-copy-id`.